# Getting age=infinity while trying to get min and max age

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a project in which I have to find the `minimum` and k age of the mice present in the cage.

the code I am using is:

```
   var earTags = "";
            var miceAge = "";
            var genoTypes = "";
            for (var curr_mice_cnt = 0, mice_len = data.mice_info.length; curr_mice_cnt < mice_len; curr_mice_cnt++ )
            {
                alert("Inside for loop");
                var m_info = data.mice_info[curr_mice_cnt];
                console.log("Mice Len="+data.mice_info.length);
                earTags = earTags + m_info.ear_tag + ", " ;
                miceAge = miceAge + m_info.age + ", ";
                genoTypes = genoTypes + getGenotypeName(m_info.genotype_id) + ", ";

                var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                var tmp;
                for (var i=miceAge.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    tmp = miceAge[i].Cost;
                    if (tmp < lowest) lowest = tmp;
                    if (tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
                }
                console.log(highest, lowest);

            }
```

Now I am trying to display the `miceage` which is as string and i want to find the min and max value of the string and the error I am getting is `Miceage=Infinity`.

Can anyone please help me implement this or can You suggest any other code to implement this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong variable inside the inner loop. You treat `miceAge` as an array of objects, but it's a string.

Comment: @Juhana, can You please suggest how to implement Miceage as a string(get max and min value)

Comment: Either you didn't understand my comment, or I don't understand yours...

Comment: No, what @Juhana means is that you are confusing two different variables, calling them both `miceAge` which is most likely causing your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code you've posted.

- First off, you don't need the inner for loop at all, since you're keeping track of the min/max over the data.mice_info array.
- Secondly, you're iterating over a miceAge in the inner loop which is a string, so miceAge[i].Cost is going to come up undefined, which will fail both the greater than/less than comparisons.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for (var curr_mice_cnt = 0, mice_len = data.mice_info.length; curr_mice_cnt < mice_len; curr_mice_cnt++ ) {
    var tmp = data.mice_info[curr_mice_cnt];
    if (tmp.age < lowest) lowest = tmp.age;
    if (tmp.age > highest) highest = tmp.age;
}
console.log(lowest, highest);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the problems with your code. You are still appending to a string. Try doing this: var foo = "1, 2, 3"; console.log(foo[2]); What do you expect to see? What actually happens?

Comment: ..I have already stored mice age in string-miceAge.I want to display max and min from that string

Comment: i have changes in my code and it is working properly ..Thanks for the help